# new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); Not Launching The Camera

Tags: java, android-camera

I've been trying to create an app on Android Studio which has a button inside and once you click it your camera should be launched.

This portion of my code keeps returning `null` so it keeps printing "Null" which is unexpected to happen.

```
public void capturePhoto(View view) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "The button was clicked.");
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
           
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Not null");

            startForResult.launch(takePictureIntent);
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Null");
        }
    }
```

And a side note, it prints out "The button was clicked." so there is nothing wrong with the click event.

I've tried asking for camera access once they launch the app. Even tho the app has camera access it still doesn't work once I click the button.